# n indistinguishable balls, m distinguishable boxes , m>n

Tags: combinatorics

Given $n$ indistinguishable particles and $m>n$ distinguishable boxes, we place at random each particle in one of the boxes. What is the probability that in $n$ preselected boxes, one and only one particle will be found is?

I think the answer should be for $1/m^n$ since the ways should be $^mC_n/m^n$ but since the boxes are preselected the answer would come out to be $1/m^n$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{m^n}$ is valid  for *distinguishable* balls in distinguishable boxes

Comment: The problem is you state " we place at **random** each particle in one of the boxes." Consider just two particles. By random placement they are always more likely to be in different boxes rather than in the same box, so placement using stars and bars won't yield equiprobable placements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is incorrect because when you do $m^n$, you are treating each particle separately by giving each one $m$ choices, essentially making them "distinguishable." To see this, let's say you give the first choice to particle $p_1$, second choice to $p_2$, and so on, all the way to $p_n$. Then you will see that something like $$p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4,\ldots,p_n,E,E,\dots,E$$
where $E$ represents empty boxes would be counted differently from
$$p_2,p_1,p_3,p_4,\ldots,p_n,E,E,\ldots,E$$
when, in fact, they should be counted the same. To account for this, you would need actually need to do a method known as [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), which you can look into further in the Wikipedia page linked.

Comment: Stars and Bars insufficient.  See the answer of true blue anil.

Answer (score 0):

You run into a problem here. As I commented, (and as a subsequent answer has explained in detail), the formula you write is valid only for *distinguishable* balls in distinguishable boxes.

Further, if the balls are treated as indistinguishable, the unrestricted **number of ways** can be found out by stars and bars  as $\binom{n+m-1}{n} = D\;\;(say)$ ways, **but these are not equiprobable ways**. You can easily understand that having all $n$ particles in one box is far more unlikely than a more even distribution.

### Added

The question mentions "...we place at random each particle in one of the boxes." I take it to mean (as in classical die throws prototype) that
particles get placed into bins independently and uniformly. It would therefore be wrong to use stars and bars (which is just a bin  tuples count) as equiprobable.

As a simple example, if you throw a D6 twice,

it is *known* that you will get $6*6 = 36$ equiprobable results,
whereas stars and bars will yield $\binom{2+6-1}{6-1} = 21$ results. Obviously they can't be equiprobable !

In fact, getting two different occupancies, eg $13/31$, or $25/52$, is twice as likely as getting two of a kind, e.g. $33$ or $66$

Comment: I think I might be wrong here but I feel like they actually have equal probability. If the boxes were indistinguishable, then I would think that the probability is not all equal but we are dealing with distinguishable boxes here. Can you clarify for me?

Comment: Also a minor issue but can easily be fixed, it should be $m-1$ at the bottom of the binomial term, not $n$.

Comment: @AidenChow: The two are equivalent !

Comment: Ah yep true, I always learned the formula the other way so I didn't realize they were equivalent.

Comment: Can you still clarify my first comment? Thanks

Comment: @AidenChow: I will add in my answer presently.

Comment: Ok sounds good.... but I am correct or wrong?

Comment: I have added, using stars and bars here is wrong. See the example.

Comment: But in your rolling two D6 example, that would be equivalent to putting two distinguishable particles into six distinguishable bins (in fact this is OP's $m^n$ answer with $m=6$ and $n=2$ if I understand correctly), whereas the stars and bars method would be equivalent to putting two indistinguishable particles into six distinguishable bins. Is my understanding accurate or is it wrong?

Comment: I wanted to clarify what exactly you meant with the rolling two D6 example in relation to the problem, because this seems to me like you take one particle and have $6$ bins for that, then another particle and have another $6$ bins for that, resulting in $36$ equally likely scenarios. Is that what you meant?

Comment: The trouble is the question states you  are putting the particles in *randomly*, so two particles are more likely to be in different bins rather than in the same bin.

Comment: Ok I thought of this problem for a while and I think I understand now, you will have to multiply by the number of ways to choose each particle into their particular bins for each composition of $n$.